# Unity 2d sprite details looking different at small size and in big numbers

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am trying to create grid with small squares, my square sprite has a black outline but the outline looks thicker at some areas and thinner in some other areas. How can i fix it?

Here is the look i got by snapping them without leaving any place inbetween.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/gdIY6.jpg

Comment: That might just be how your version is rendering them. Also, this isn't really a scripting error and might be better in the Unity forum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done some testing to reproduce your screenshot, and at the end I think this is a very simple problem: Unity does that when it tries to render high definition sprites with a low scale ( think of it as multiple pixels of a sprite fighting each other for one pixel of your screen ), so for you I think the solution would be to use less detailled sprites.

Comment: Checking the "Generate Mip Maps" also gives the same result. I am not so sure about what it exactly does but I believe it lowers the resolution of sprites used for scaled down objects.